# 'No tests found in your file:' when using Before Hook in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm attempting to use a Before Hook to run some commands however I keep being presented with 'No tests found in your file:'

```
describe("Test hook", function ()

{before("Before", function(){cy.log("Testing")})})
```

This is all I have in my .js, Cypress is able to find the .js file no problem and will run my code as expected when I'm not trying to use a before hook.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: You *don't* have any tests, just a `before` hook in a `describe` suite. You need an `it`/`test`, that's what defines an actual test.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was expecting to be able to use cy commands inside of the before hook? So I was expecting Cypress to log "Testing" even if I didn't have other tests in there.

Comment: You can use cy commands in the hook, it's not saying that's a problem, the problem is you don't have any actual tests. Even an empty `it("", function () {})` would be enough.

Comment: So my code is now

```
describe("Test hook", function ()

{

before("Before", function(){



cy.url('https://www.google.co.uk/')



}) }



)



describe('This is a sample test', function () {
  it('Compares true to true', function (){expect(true).to.equal(true)})

})
```

The compare tests runs as expected, but what am I missing for the cy.url to work? I was expecting it to load Google in the Before hook, but it's stayed on the default web page?

Thanks

Comment: If you still have a problem, please [edit] the question. But it's unclear why you expected that to load Google, given how that command is described in the docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html.

Comment: ah yes sorry, I meant: cy.visit('https://www.google.co.uk/')

But the point is that none of my cy commands are being executed in the Before Hook?

Comment: It is not a good solution, but I had once accidentally put a before hook on its own in support/index.js and it worked before each test. Though I always prefer such repetitive actions to be a custom command that can be called only when needed.